# How to change a dictionary into an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, dictionary, adjacency-matrix

I have a dictionary **avgTE_data**:

```
{'20180102':  SYM_ROOT_i  SYM_ROOT_j   DATE_dat    TE
       0        A           AAL       20180102   0.125528
       1        A           AAP       20180102   0.283033
       2        A           AAPL      20180102   0.042315
     ...        ...         ...         ...       ...
     247008     ZTS         ZION      20180102   0.193963

'20180103':    SYM_ROOT_i  SYM_ROOT_j   DATE_dat    TE
       0        A           AAL       20180103   0.189076
       1        A           AAP       20180103   0.469080
       2        A           AAPL      20180103   0.689097
     ...        ...         ...         ...       ...
     247504     ZTS         ZION      20180103   0.645870

...         ...            ...        ...        ...
'20180131':    SYM_ROOT_i  SYM_ROOT_j   DATE_dat    TE
       0        A           AAL       20180131   0.568890
       1        A           AAP       20180131   0.267990
       2        A           AAPL      20180131   0.578768
     ...        ...         ...         ...       ...
     247504     ZTS         ZION      20180131   0.523764}
```

I want to change this dictionary into an adjacency matrix like this:

```
                                      
           A         AAL        AAP         ...      ZTS
   A       0         avg_TE1    avg_TE2     ...      avg_TEn
  AAL     avg_TEn     0         avg_TEn     ...      avg_TEn
  AAP      ...       ...        0           ...       ...
  ...      ...       ...        ...         ...       ...
  ZTS     avg_TEn    avg_TEn    avg_TEn     ...       0
```

**avg_TE** means the average TE from 20180102 to 20180131. The horizontal is SYM_ROOT_i and the vertical is SYM_ROOT_j. Do anyone know how to do it in python? Thanks!

Comment: Try looking into this, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353759/how-do-i-generate-an-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph-from-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: Are the values in your `dict` pandas `DataFrame`s?  I would say break this down in to parts and take it one step at a time.  What might be the first step?